# Math.Round with double value

Tags: c#

```
double? AssessmentTotal=2.345;
double? AssessmentTotalval = Math.Round((decimal)AssessmentTotal == null ? 0 : AssessmentTotal, 2);
```

I'm trying to Round up a double value. Expected result is 2.35

I'm getting a build error.

> Error 40  The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Math.Round(double, int)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Why not just use `AssessmentTotal.GetValueOrDefault()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing it like this:

```
double? AssessmentTotal = 2.345;
double? AssessmentTotalval = Math.Round(AssessmentTotal.GetValueOrDefault(), 2);
```

There are a number of issues with your current approach.

First, the condition `(decimal)AssessmentTotal == null` only evaluates to true if `AssessmentTotal` is not null. As soon as it is `null` you get a "InvalidOperationException: Nullabl object must have a value." exception. Calling `AssessmentTotal.GetValueOrDefault()` avoids that issue.

Second, `Math.Round(...)` takes either a `double` or `decimal` - by using `0` you make your code less readable (and possibly buggy). You should always use either `0.0` for `double` or `0m` for `decimal`. In your case you should use `0.0` since you are dealing with a `double`.

---

As per your comment re rounding up `49.625` you need to change the code to this:

```
double? AssessmentTotal = 49.625;
double? AssessmentTotalval = Math.Round(AssessmentTotal.GetValueOrDefault(), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

The `MidpointRounding` default is `MidpointRounding.ToEven` - you want `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`.

Comment: and `AssessmentTotalval` is `double` and not `double?` at this point :-)

Comment: @xanatos - According to the OP's code he wants it as `double?`.

Comment: Hello @Enigmativity I tried.   double? AssessmentTotal = 49.625;
            double? AssessmentTotalval = Math.Round(AssessmentTotal.GetValueOrDefault(), 2); it returns 49.62 but it has to be 49.63

Comment: I don't think the second assignment needs to be nullable.  All other answer cast to decimal which could introduce precision errors.

Comment: @DavidMartin - I don't know what the rest of the OP's code is and whether or not the second assignment can be `double` or if it has to be `double?`.

Answer (score 4):

Considering that rounding is a non-inexpensive operation, you could:

```
double? AssessmentTotalval = AssessmentTotal == null ? 
                    0.0 : 
                    Math.Round(AssessmentTotal.Value, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

and bypass totally the `Math.Round` if the `AssessmentTotal` is `null`.

Note that at this point `AssessmentTotalval` is always != `null`, so it is useless to have a `double?`

Note even the use of `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`, otherwise `0.005` would become `0` instead of `0.01`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like below.

```
double? AssessmentTotal=2.345;
double? AssessmentTotalval = AssessmentTotal.HasValue ? Math.Round(AssessmentTotal.Value,2) : (double?)null;
```

If you want 0 when AssessmentTotal is null
then you can modify the above code  as below.

```
double? AssessmentTotal=2.345;
double? AssessmentTotalval = AssessmentTotal.HasValue ? Math.Round(AssessmentTotal.Value,2) : (double?)0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double? AssessmentTotal=2.345;
double? AssessmentTotalval = Math.Round((decimal)AssessmentTotal == null ? 0 
 : AssessmentTotal.Value, 2);
Console.WriteLine(AssessmentTotalval);
```

** Correction **

The code above is throwing error if the value is null. The code below is working better

```
double? AssessmentTotalval = AssessmentTotal != null ? Math.Round(AssessmentTotal.Value, 2) : 0;
```

Comment: It is returning the expected result!

Comment: Try changing `AssessmentTotal` to `null` - `InvalidOperationException` is then thrown.

Answer (score -1):

you are missing 'm'. It should be 0.0m in your condition. 0 by default is int in most cases and 0.0 by default is double.

**edit**

Taking a closer look at it , looks like you are just converting double to decimal while comparing with null only , result is still double or implicit conversion of int 0 to double. However I suggest you modify your result to be decimal and do the rounding like in the formula I provided below. I will explain the reason later when I am at PC, if you want. But right now I am typing from my iPhone 5 and it's darn difficult .:(

While you are at it, you should also take a look at rounding it with mid- point rounding. 
Math.Round((Decimal)d, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))

Answer (score -2):

```
double? AssessmentTotalval = Convert.ToDouble((AssessmentTotal ?? 0).ToString("N2"));
```

Comment: some explanation might help

Comment: @deW1 things which are easy to understand do not require explanation. I have just used string format "N2"